# Python performance: repeating calculations vs temp variable

Tags: python, performance, variables

Does python recalculate every repeating expression in code?
For example does

```py
a = [1,23,45,45,456,34]

b = len(a) + 213
c = len(a) + 3432
```

differ in performance from

```py
a = [1,23,45,45,456,34]
l = len(a)
b = l + 213
c = l + 3432
```

I would guess second one uses more memory (to store l) but less cpu. Am I correct?

Comment: Hello Hello, in general the 2nd case is better form to save re-calculating

Comment: In the ideal situation `l` should be garbage collected after it's last use, but normally in Python you shouldn't have to worry about this (especially if `l` is really just an integer)

Comment: Chris_Rands can we be sure it is garbage collected? Is it better to use 2nd case in long cycles or can it cause memory leak?

Comment: `len(a)` would be an O(1) operation anyway (length of a list is known), so there wouldn't really be a difference in performance because no "calculations" are being performed to give you the length of the list.

Comment: Python handles memory management well so it should not be a concern, if there are no references to an object gc should operate (you can enforce it if you like). Pranav is correct about len(a) too though

Answer (score 1):

> Does python recalculate every repeating expression in code?

It is **unspecified** in the language specification. In fact, this is highly **dependent of the Python implementation**. The mainstream Python implementation, called **CPython, does recompute the expression**. PyPy (an alternative implementation focusing on performance) usually do not recompute the expression in hot portions of the code, thanks to just-in-time compilation. There are many other implementation of Python (eg. Pyston, Jython, IronPython) and each one can behave differently.

> I would guess second one uses more memory (to store l) but less cpu.

Yes, but the difference is actually marginal and still dependent of the Python implementation used (eg. PyPy may not require more memory in this case). Note that calling `len` on a `list` is very fast and this is done in constant time.

While the *second code should be slightly faster*, such micro-optimization will likely have no significant impact on a big code. Keep in mind that readable code are generally easier to maintain, improve and optimize.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please share your thoughts on the same question regarding  C and  C++ ?

Comment: What do you mean? Whether repeated expressions are optimized in C and C++ or not? If you enable *optimization flags* of mainstream compilers (like `-O3` in GCC/Clang/ICC or `/O2` in MSVC), then the resulting program should not recompute the expression as long as the expression if free of any *side effects*. This is called [common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination). Note that this is much harder to do the same thing in Python since it is a very dynamic language (eg. dynamic typing, operator/function redefinition at runtime, etc.).